# Download File to Downloads Folder From Server ActionForward/Struts/Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, struts

I am trying to download a file from my web application in an ActionForward java class. I have looked at many examples to try different solutions but none have worked so far. My knowledge is limited and have spent a good amount of time to get this to work.

From my jsp page a link hits an action in my struts config which takes the thread to an ActionForward return type method on a java class.

I then take the passed in file name and grab it from an amazon s3 bucket. With the file downloaded from the s3 bucket I now have the file bytes[].

I need to then have the file download to the local machine as most files do (appearing in the downloads folder and the web showing the download at the bottom bar of the page)

After following some examples I kept getting this error

```
Servlet Exception - getOutputStream() has already been called for this 
response
```

I got past the error by doing

```
response.getOutputStream().write
```

Instead of creating a new OutputStream like this

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
```

Now it runs without errors but no file gets downloaded.

Here is the java file I am attempting to do this in.

As you can see in the file below is a commented out DownloadServlet class which I tried as another attempt. I did this because a lot of the examples have classes the extends HttpServlet which I made DownloadServlet extend but it made no difference.

```
package com.tc.fms.actions;

    import com.sun.media.jai.util.PropertyUtil;
    import com.tc.fw.User;
    import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessage;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.tc.fw.actions.BaseAction;
    import org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile;


    import io.isfs.utils.ObjectUtils;


    import com.tc.fw.*;
    import com.tc.fms.*;
    import com.tc.fms.service.*;


public class FileDownloadAction extends BaseAction {

private static ObjectUtils objectUtils = new ObjectUtils();
private final int ARBITARY_SIZE = 1048;

public ActionForward performWork(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("In File Download Action");
    ActionMessages errors = new ActionMessages();
    User user = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute(User.lookupKey);
    String fileName = (String) PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(form, "fileName");
    String outboundDir = (String) PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(form, "outboundDir");
    System.out.println("File Dir: " + outboundDir + " File Name: " + fileName);
    try{
        try {
// Get file from amazon
            byte[] fileBytes = objectUtils.getFileDavid(outboundDir, fileName);
            if (fileBytes != null) {
                java.io.File file = File.createTempFile(fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".") - 1), fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")));
                FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fileOuputStream.write(fileBytes);
                try {
/*                        DownloadServlet downloadServlet = new DownloadServlet();
                    downloadServlet.doGet(request, response, file);*/

                    response.setContentType("text/plain");
                    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());

                    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                    /*OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();*/

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[ARBITARY_SIZE];

                    int numBytesRead;
                    while ((numBytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        response.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("OutputStream EROOR: " + e);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("File Bytes Are Null");
                errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("fms.download.no.file.found"));
                saveErrors(request, errors);
                return mapping.findForward("failure");
                // Failed
            }
        } catch (Exception eee){
            System.out.println("Failed in AWS ERROR: " + eee);
            errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("fms.download.failed"));
            saveErrors(request, errors);
            return mapping.findForward("failure");
        }
    }catch (Exception ee){
        System.out.println("Failed in global try");
        errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("fms.download.failed"));
        saveErrors(request, errors);
        return mapping.findForward("failure");
    }
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
}
```

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-download-file-from-website-example/

Comment: There are many examples of how to download a file in Struts 1 on the web. That aside, this class does too many things. There are least two major refactorings to do, and a few minor ones. Doing so will make this code *much* easier to deal with.